# NPM - PM2 application disappears/uninstalling alone randomly

Tags: npm, debian, pm2

I have a Debian server running with Plesk.
This server hosts the pedagogical platform I created.
This platform uses WebSocket technology to allow teachers and students interactions in real time.

From the side server, a nodejs script started by PM2 manages all this.

My problem is that in a totally random way and without anyone doing anything, PM2 "uninstall" alone and the WebSocket server stops working ...

I can solve the problem easily using:
`NPM Install -G PM2`  and restart the script.

The hours are never the same and do not match with a cron task:

- First time early December in the morning
- Wednesday, December 22 in the morning

*(I then create a monitoring with Uptime Robot)*

- Thursday January 13 at 5:12 am (GMT+1)
- Wednesday, January 26 at 15:57 pm (GMT+1)

I can't find anything in log files ...

It's really problematic because we have many users and a continuity of service to ensure.

Any ideas ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by Plesk which deletes the elements installed globally in /opt/plesk/node/17/bin
I changed approach. I installed PM2 locally in an other folder.
Problem solved.